# developing web application in android

Tags: android

I want to develop an android application that will access web pages.Like my browser will first load "www.mail.yahoo.com".then it automatically set yahoo id and password that i will tell from my program.then it will automatically click in sign in to sign in.Like web browser control in visual basic 6 or in c# application.In android i can browse pages using web view but not getting any way to access html content as i have been trying for a week.If any body will help it will be great pleasure.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WebView` for accessing URLs and let the users see the content.

A poorman's solution to get the HTML is to open the URL with another `HttpConnection` in another thread and read the contents of it. just because I haven't find any other way to access the HTML that is loaded in the WebView

Comment: Sir, I need both reading and writing. Using webView i am getting whole page as a string.I have to get it according to html tag and have to put values.

Comment: are you able to get the HTML as a string!?